# Grails Custom URL for branding purposes

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I need to brand my page (i.e. custom images) based on the URL Context Path. I already have the the URL Mapping:

```
"/enrollment/$client/$action/" {
        controller = "enrollment"
    }
```

But, I can't seem to get the controller to respect the custom URLs.

Example of what I want is when I am on a page like this: localhost:8080/enrollment/insurance-a/index 
I want to be able to navigate to the next page in the work flow, which would hopefully be this: localhost:8080/enrollment/insurance-a/thanks
But, when I render the view, it goes to: localhost:8080/enrollment/thanks

Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "respect the custom URLs"? What is happening exactly? What's not right about what's happening? What do you expect to happen instead? You need to provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: Do you have this before or after the default url mappings?

Comment: I removed the default mappings.

Comment: I added an example description of what I want.